# Support syntax scheme.prisma file by IDE

Tags: reactjs, syntax, webstorm, prisma, highlight

Why when create Prisma schema file, I have no code syntax support? I mean, after running the following command

```
npx prisma init --datasource-provider sqlite
```

I'm getting `scheme.prisma` file (and `DATABASE_URL="file:./dev.db"` - in .env file), but I can't use support suggestions actions. All text in the file have white color (without suggestions and syntax highlighting):

[image]

I've tried adding an ORM extension plugin, but not getting any results.

Comment: You can restart IDE or reinstall the extension

Comment: @Khuong Viet Tai - Already restarted.. not changed

Comment: If you select that file in the Project View panel, then invoke `View | Quick Documentation` on it (`Ctrl+Q` here on Windows), what will it show? Share the popup screenshot -- mainly interested in what file type the IDE thinks it is.

Comment: @LazyOne I have no "Quick Documentation" item, but i`m understanding what you mean. Ok, i will try.

Answer (score 0):

"Prisma ORM" plugin (from webstorm plugins marketplace) re-install helped!